# Bilingual site page URL issues

Tags: localization, url, settings

I'm trying to setup a bilingual site and I'm having some issues with setting up the URI.

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://localhost/mysite',
    'fr' => 'http://localhost/mysite/fr',
),
'environmentVariables' => array(
    'baseUrl'  => 'http://localhost/mysite/',
)
```

In my single settings:
URI for french: {baseUrl}fr/nouvelles
URI for english: {baseUrl}news

Not sure how to set this up to have it setup the way I want it.  Removing the baseURL part just doesn't print the mysite subfolder.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Here's the real problematic after investigation.

The URI should not include anything more than the name so:
In my single settings:
URI for french: nouvelles (http://localhost/mysite/fr/nouvelles)
URI for english: news (http://localhost/mysite/news)

Now, those 2 pages work like expected.

But, if I assign those pages to a Entries field, to create my menu, when I pull the url, it never inclues the /fr portion.  Even the default template doesn't render the correct link, dropping the /fr part in the url too:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').limit(5).find() %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you added the physical subfolder (with index.php in it etc.) to your wwwroot for the secondary language? You do not need {baseUrl} in your Section slug settings.

Comment: Yes! I should specify that everything works like it should when I visit the pages.  But, not when I try to access the page's url, or the other locale page's url.
http://localhost/cartovista/ is in english 
http://localhost/cartovista/fr is in french

I think I'm getting things confused in the URI part.  I don't think it requires the fr part.  I will dig a bit more but if someone understands my issue and has already setup a bilingual site, with language switch, I would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Ok, I have now pinpointed my issue to url in the twig template.  Anytime a page url is called, the fr portion is never included, which renders the link useless.

link.page[0].url
link page, being a Entries field type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... the answer was quite simple.

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en_ca' => 'http://localhost/mysite',
    'fr_ca' => 'http://localhost/mysite/fr',
),
```

The _ca part was what was missing.  Now my site works amazingly.

Sorry for the run around and I hope this can help someone.